# Satellite 6/Foreman: Cannot manage DHCP/DNS with libvirt

Tags: foreman

I have a Satellite 6 server on my test environment **installed as a VM** in a CentOS 7 box.
I have configured the CentOS KVM as a Compute Resource and host provisioning *(without any Capsule/Foreman Proxy)* works just fine. However, I want to use the DHCP/DNS provided by libvirt itself in order to control the IPs/hostnames of my new boxes.
According to Red Hat, Satellite 6 uses the version 1.11 of Foreman.

I followed the Red Hat documentation for external capsules as well as Foreman's documentation for the usage of libvirt as a DNS/DHCP proxy.

I have installed Satellite 6 with the following options:

> ```
> satellite-installer -S satellite 
> --foreman-proxy-dns-server kvmbox.example \
> --foreman-proxy-dns-provider virsh \
> --foreman-proxy-dns true \
> --foreman-proxy-dhcp-server kvmbox.example \
> --foreman-proxy-dhcp-provider virsh \
> --foreman-proxy-dhcp true \
> --foreman-proxy-dhcp-gateway eth0 \
> --foreman-proxy-dhcp-interface eth0
> ```

So, /etc/foreman-proxy/settings.d/dhcp.yml is:

```
---
# Enable DHCP management
# Can be true, false, or http/https to enable just one of the protocols
:enabled: https

# valid providers:
#   - dhcp_isc (ISC dhcp server)
#   - dhcp_native_ms (Microsoft native implementation)
#   - dhcp_virsh (simple implementation for libvirt)
:use_provider: dhcp_virsh
:server: kvmbox.example
# subnets restricts the subnets queried to a subset, to reduce the query time.
#:subnets: [192.168.205.0/255.255.255.128, 192.168.205.128/255.255.255.128]
```

And for DNS:

```
---
# DNS management

:enabled: https
# valid providers:
#   dns_dnscmd (Microsoft Windows native implementation)
#   dns_nsupdate
#   dns_nsupdate_gss (for GSS-TSIG support)
#   dns_virsh (simple implementation for libvirt)
:use_provider: dns_virsh
# use this setting if you want to override default TTL setting (86400)
:dns_ttl: 86400
```

My foreman-proxy configuration seems just fine. However, when I try to create a new host, I see the following error:

```
Create DHCP Settings for z1.example.com task failed with the following  
error: ERF12-6899 [ProxyAPI::ProxyException]: Unable to set DHCP entry
([RestClient::BadRequest]: 400 Bad Request) for Capsule 
https://satellite.example.com:9090/dhcp
```

The /var/log/foreman-proxy/proxy.log has the following entries:

> E, [2016-12-07T16:21:35.043048 #31931] ERROR -- : DHCP virsh provider >    error: unable to retrive virsh info: virsh provider error: virsh call >    failed (pid 32091 exit 1) - error: failed to connect to the hypervisor
>      error: Failed to connect socket to **'/var/run/libvirt/libvirt-sock'**:
>      No such file or directory

So, from these error logs and the lack of configuration options (as the *_virsh) files mentions, it seems that the only scenario in which I can use the libvirt DHCP/DNS functionality, (at least with Satellite 6.2/Foreman 1.11) is when Satellite/Foreman is installed on the Physical box, not as VM...

Is that true, or I just miss something?

Comment: Your proxy seems well configured at first glance. That error indicates some problem with libvirt, can you try running it as 'libvirtd --listen' to see if anything shows up in the logs? Maybe journald has some information too

Comment: My libvirt runs with the --listen option. I believe that the Satellite is NOT going to the host's libvirt. As you can see, the log file says that it search for the libvirt-sock file, which of course is NOT present in the VM, but in the host! And surely enough, I retested. journal is empty, and in /var/log/messages there are no DHCP requests.